# Variable argument list with Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, dll, variadic-functions

Assume I have a DLL that exports functions with variable arguments list like this:

```
int myfunc(int arg1,...)
```

Here "..." is a undefined number of additional arguments. Can such functions be called out of a Visual Basic application or is VB locked to functions with fixed arguments?

I'm just asking to avoid a design problem that would lock-out VB programmers...

Comment: This is not a duplicate, since VBA is not VB6

Comment: @KonstantinPereyaslov Agreed, but their syntax is almost identical.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In VBA, functions can hand over an undefined number of arguments, so there should be no problem.

Directly in VBA, you'd define a function like this:

```
Function SumAll(ParamArray var() As Variant) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tmp As Double
    For i = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
        If IsNumeric(var(i)) Then tmp = tmp + var(i)
    Next
    SumAll = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: Note: You can mix `ParamArray var() As Variant` with non-optional arguments. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OptionalArgumentsToProcedures.aspx