# Syntax error when passing variable args in macro

Tags: vba, libreoffice

I have a macro for libreoffice that takes in 2 arguments.

1. A file path
2. Variable args that are sheet names to look for.

I iterate over the document pertaining to the first arg and get the sheet that matches the first variable arg. I then convert that sheet to CSV.

```
Sub ExportToCsv(URL as String, ParamArray sheetNames() As Variant)
  Dim saveParams(1) as New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
  saveParams(0).Name = "FilterName"
  saveParams(0).Value = "Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)"
  saveParams(1).Name = "FilterOptions"
  saveParams(1).Value = "44,34,0,1,1" ' 44=comma, 34=double-quote

  GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.loadLibrary("Tools")
  URL = ConvertToURL(URL)
  document = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromUrl(URL, "_blank", 0,  Array())

  baseName = Tools.Strings.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(document.GetURL(), "/")
  directory = Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameoutofPath(document.GetURL(), "/")

  sheets = document.Sheets
  sheetCount = sheets.Count
  Dim x as Integer
  Dim requiredSheetIndex as Integer
  For x = 0 to sheetCount -1
    sheet = sheets.getByIndex(x)
    sheet.isVisible = True
    For i = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
      If StrComp(sheet.Name, sheetNames(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        requiredSheetIndex = x
      End If
    Next
  Next

  currentSheet = document.GetCurrentController.GetActiveSheet()
  sheet = sheets(requiredSheetIndex)
  document.GetCurrentController.SetActiveSheet(sheet)
  filename = directory + "/" + baseName + ".csv"
  fileURL = convertToURL(Filename)
  document.StoreToURL(fileURL, saveParams())
  document.close(True)
End Sub
```

Eg. `ExportToCsv(<path>, 'Data')`. Suppose the document has 4 sheets with the 3rd sheet as `DATA`, this sheet should be converted to CSV.

Previously I used to give the sheet idnex directly into the macro and it worked perfectly. But requirements changed and I have to pass in an array of possible names to match on. Hence the variable args.

But now I am getting a syntax error(Screenshot attached). I cant figure out what is wrong here.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Don't you just need `Sub ExportToCsv(URL as String, sheetNames As Variant)` ? Or because you're on `libreoffice` at least get rid of the brackets for `sheetNames()` (not sure what the `ParamArray` is for either).

Comment: The macros tag says "DO NOT USE for VBA", so removed.

Comment: Ok. I was not aware. Thanks

Comment: @jamheadart I am not well versed with vba. I was using this as a reference - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716385/variable-argument-list-with-visual-basic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is complaining about the ParamArray keyword.  After a little digging, I discovered you need to include:

```
option compatible
```

at the top of your module.  For more information, you can [refer to this link](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/166628/how-to-write-a-function-with-arbitrary-number-of-arguments/).

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I am still facing issues in other areas but the compilation has succeeded now.